# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it "exception"

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

in my project i have text box and when the event fire `_rtpAudioChannel_ChannelStateChanged` **i get this exception The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it**

```
      void _rtpAudioChannel_ChannelStateChanged(object sender, RtpStateChangedEventArgs<RtpChannelState> e)
      {
            AddNewState("some text here");
      }


      public void AddNewState(string state)
      {
            StatTextBox.Text = state + "\n" + StatTextBox.Text;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For technical reasons, windows and controls created in one thread cannot be accessed from any other thread. To resolve the problem you have to "forward" the control-accessing operation (getting and setting `Text`) to the appropriate thread, which in WPF is called the *dispatcher thread*.

Do this by calling [`StatTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604732) (which is synchronous, i.e. does not return until the processing is complete) or [`StatTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604730) (which is asynchronous and offers better performance).

Comment: thanks Jon but i can not use my method here because it has a parameter .. sorry for my bad English

Comment: @tito11: Of course you can, and not only in one way. Example: `StatTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(this.AddNewState, "some text here")`. Although the code could use some restructuring.

Answer (score 1):

the ultimate solution:
looked for hours by this..
you can call the SetMSG(text) function from wherever you want.
and it will set the StatTextBox.Text to text.

```
 public void SetMSG(string text){

        if (StatTextBox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            StatTextBox.Text = text;
        }
        else
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            StatTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, d, text);
        }
    }
    delegate void SetTextCallBack(string Text);

    public void SetText(string text){
        StatTextBox.Text=text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    StatTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        StatTextBox.Text = "some text here" + "\n" + StatTextBox.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are use windows forms, you shoul access to window control from the same thread, as where the control was created or use marshalling.

You can use this variant in your code:

```
var lambda = () => StatTextBox.Text = "some text here" + "\n" + StatTextBox.Text;
if (StatTextBox.InvokeRequired)
{
    control.Invoke(lambda, new object[0]);
}
else
{
    lambda();
}
```